# Find unique values in a range that occur a minimum number of times

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

I am trying to cut down on some manual work I do by using Excel functions. Each day I have a list of statistics that I need to analyze, and all values vary in one way or another. Each spreadsheet has about 10 columns and upwards of 10,000 rows of data. This is what I need to do:

Find all unique values in one column that occur a minimum number of times (excluding empty cells). Then I need that data to be sorted from most occurring to least occurring.

**For example, assuming the minimum frequency required to show up on the list is 2:**

```
Blue
Blue
<empty cell>
Green
Green
Green
Green
<empty cell>
Red
Red
Red
Yellow
```

**Should display as:**

```
Green
Red
Blue
```

The reason why I need it to be done with functions is because I will be creating these lists for 5-6 of the columns that display the most frequent values from each column separate from each other. Using filters and manually sorting data takes an hour for each sheet, whereas having a set of functions would analyze all of the data at once and I can spend my time more efficiently.

If it makes any difference, I am using Microsoft Excel 2011 for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can easily do that using Tools->Subtotals and Tools->PivotTables

refer this - http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-HA010095247.aspx

Answer (score 0):

#### Sorted list of unique values that occur a given number of times

1. Set up a header row. You need it later for correct filtering
2. Enter two formulas in B2 and C2 and autofill both down to show only values which occur two or more times. But still with empty cells and unsorted

   ```
   B2: =IF(COUNTA(A1:$A$100000,A2)=2,A2,"")
   C2: =COUNTIF(A:A,A2)
   ```

   - Change `=2` if you want values with a higher occurrence
   - If your data column has more than 100000 entries you have to set a higher number.
     I chose 100000 only to keep the formula simple
3. Sort your table: Select your table without the header row and go to
   `Data → Sort → Column C → Largest to smallest`
   [image][image]
4. Hide empty rows: Select column B and go to `Data → Filter → untick "empty"`
   [image]